# I want to put values from additional database in drupal 7. How can I do it?

Tags: 7, views

I wanted to include additional values to the drupal site. Since it has around 3000 records and it is divided into categories ( a:1, a:2, a:3, b:1, b:2, c:1, c:2, c:3), I had set additional database and connected to drupal.
My question is:
How can I get those values into drupal? views? They have to be included in two forms as a checkboxes and value lists on other form to choose.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using a different database, you should be able to create a table in your Drupal DB and add them there. Which Drupal version are you using?

Comment: I would like to keep data on different database as I thought this may help me to maintain it when i had to upgrade or update Drupal. Value of this lists are taken to the form and they are integral part of the system. I even think that a module that includes this values will be a good option to keep data clean, maintain, re-install then needed, and so forth.... There are 2 value lists. First contains more than 3000 records, second around 400 records. Both are 2 levels lists. Am I correct in my thinking?.. or there may be a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

This thread: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/how-do-i-display-an-external-database-data discusses this issue quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using Drupal 6, I would suggest using the [Data module](http://drupal.org/project/data), however in Drupal 7 there isn't an equivalent. The Data module would have connected data in two different databases in Drupal if they were described in settings.php.

If you know a little PHP and basics of the Drupal API you can use the new [Field API](http://drupal.org/node/707832). It's pretty straight forward using the hook_field_scheme() to define the database table and the standard Field API hooks to create fields that can be attached to entities in the Drupal Admin UI.

You can use hook_theme() to define different templates that renders the data in different ways and hook_field_formatter_view() to call different theme functions and templates that you create. Views integration is wonderful because if you create several different formatters when you select the field in the Field section of Views UI it will give you a drop down choice of what formatter to use.

In this case if you're importing the data you don't need to attach the field to a content type, nevertheless, if the data at some point needs to be updated, added to, or deleted dynamically it is already to go with only using four or five different functions.

I have a case where I have a single address field defined but it includes city, state, country, zip, lat, lng, ect. in each row of the database table. However, I have 5 different formatters, one with only lat and lng converted to degrees, another with only the city and state, and one with the entire address as a vcard with a call to google to return a static map with a marker. In views I just choose which formatter to use with the information.

Comment: Thank you, I have installed Data Module. I think it helps a lot, actually it will help if I can figure out how to work out this error message: user warning: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'maxvalue) VALUES (5, 'id_model', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'int', 1, 4122)' at line 1 query: INSERT INTO tw_columns (twtid, colname, weight, primarykey, availablefk, secure, ignorecol, isempty, coltype, minvalue, maxvalue) VALUES (5, 'id_model', 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 'int', 1, 4122) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/autocze